# Returning StringTokenizer to be able to setText on a Textarea

Tags: java, string, jlabel, jtextarea, stringtokenizer

Dunno what to do, what is the best way to do this.

this code is in my actionlistner for a button if clicked

```
text = stringtokenizer(text);
ta2.setText(text);
```

ta2 is a textarea

this is the method for stringtokenizer

```
public static StringTokenizer stringtokenizer(String text) {

    StringTokenizer tx = new StringTokenizer(text);

    while (tx.hasMoreElements()) {

        System.out.println(tx.nextElement());
    }

    return tx;

}
```

how can i be able to return the elements and print it in the textarea.

Comment: `stringTokenizer` retruns `StringTokenizer` and takes a `String`, so `text = stringTokenizer(text)` isn't valid? Unless `StringTokenizer` is a subclass of `String`? Also what is `ta2`?

Comment: The StringTokenizer is primarily used to split strings and iterate those elements. You will need to use StingBuilder / StringBuffer /ArrayList / Array[]  to store the results you want to return

Comment: Okay, completely lost, what exactly are you trying to achieve (don't worry about what you've tried), what you trying to do...

Comment: code is in a jframe. ta2 is a text area, im trying to return the tokens/elements from the method and output/print it in the ta2. yea this is not valid at all. @MadProgrammer

Comment: @KennethClark i found some arraylist but still i dont know how to be able to return it and print it in a text area.

Comment: So, you have a `String` value, you want to "split it" by some token and then display the results within a `JTextArea`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by ditching `StringTokenzier`, it's been depreciated (more or less) in favor of `String#split`

```
String[] tokens = text.split(" ");
```

This will return an array of `String`s split around the supplied token (space in this case).

Next, with a `for-loop`, append each token to the `JTextArea`...

```
for (String token : tokens) {
    ta2.append(token);
    ta2.append("\n");
}
```

Before you ask for simpler solution, I can make it much more complicated if you prefer ;)